# Interval of Existence of this Bernoulli equation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$2y'+\tan(x)\cdot y=\frac {(4x+6)^2}{\cos(x)}\cdot y^3$$ with the initial conditions $|y(0)|=2$

I calculated the explicit solution as $$y(x)=\left(\frac {-3\cos x}{16x^3 +72x^2 + 108x-3/4}\right)^{1/2}$$

I can't seem to figure out the interval of existence for this, considering the initial value...

Any help?

Comment: Is it $(\frac{-\pi}{2},0)$

Comment: Don't know the answer...

Comment: The fraction is still positive at $x=0$, so one can go a little bit to the left, up to about $x=0.0069125..$ // It would simplify the analysis a little if you cancel the sign in the fraction, so that numerator and denominator are positive at $x=0$.

Comment: So @ahson 's solution is acceptable?

Comment: Yes and no, the domain should contain some small neighborhood of the initial point location $x=0$ on both sides. So with the restriction $0<x<1$ the denominator in the current form stays negative for $(16+72+108)x-\frac34<0$, which could be refined with the tighter restriction $x<0.01$ to $(0.0016+0.72+108)x<\frac34$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha points out the polynomial in the denominator is $(x+3/2)^3 - 219/4$.

Comment: Oops: $16(x+\frac{3}{2})^3 - \frac{219}{4}$

Comment: @lutz Thank you! I never knew we could approach it in such a way!